# Json ISO Date not deserialized as DateTime object

Tags: .net, json, macos, mono

I am creating a multiplatform application that works on .net/mono and uses Newtonsoft.Json to serialize information.

All worked well until I tried to send information between the machines with exactly the same version of Newtonsoft.Json.dll.

What turned out it that dates were properly serialized in the ISO format like that: **"2013-02-08T12:11:39Z"**, but when I try to deserialize them on Mac OS I get a string back instead of DateTime object!

I did some experiments using the serializer settings:

```
private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTime,
    Converters = new JsonConverter [] { new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" } }
};

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object> ("\"2013-02-08T10:11:51Z\"", jsonSettings);
```

But the result is till exactly the same string **"2013-02-08T10:11:51Z"**. I did some more experiments and it turned out that using exactly the same settings I am not able to serialize and deserialize the date like that:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now, jsonSettings), jsonSettings);
```

I still get a string representing the ISO date. After that I tried this too:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now));
```

And now I get the proper DateTime object as a result. But running the following code shows that the way the date is serialized is not exactly the ISO format:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now);
```

Returns something like **"\"2013-02-08T12:22:25.974177+02:00\""** which is not standart and will not be able to work for communication.

The weirdest part is that I had a client wit a Mac that had no such problems. I am starting to think that this is somehow related to the OS, but then wouldn't the exact format specified by me fix that?

Comment: fwiw, "2013-02-08T12:22:25.974177+02:00" *is* a standard format (see the ["Time offsets from UTC section" here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC)). But I do sympathise: JSON date handling is a minefield.